# How to query Terms under a specific TermSet for custom properties?

Tags: 2013, taxonomy

i have a TergmGroup and under this a TermSet called "Automotive". Under this TermSet i have hierarchical Terms. How can i "query" the terms under this TermSet for two Custom Properties?

I have the following Custom Properties set for each Term in my TermStore:

ID
MODEL

I want something like this:

SELECT * FROM **TERMSET**-AUTOMOTIVE
WHERE **CUSTOM-PROPERTY**-ID = 12 AND **CUSTOM-PROPERTY**-MODEL = "S600"

How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this has worked for me:

```
TaxonomySession taxSession = new TaxonomySession(rootSite);
TermStore termStore = taxSession.TermStores.DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == managedMetadataServiceName);
Group termGroup = termStore.Groups.DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == managedMetadataGroupName);
TermSet termSet = termGroup.TermSets.DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == managedMetadataTermSetName);
```

...and then you can iterate through the termset using Linq if you want with the criteria you have. For instance (this is untested code so bear with me; the pseudo-code is really what you should be interested in):

```
List<Term> termList = termSet.FindAll(x => x.LocalCustomProperties["ID"] == "12" && x.LocalCustomProperties["Model"] == "S600");
```

A couple things to note:
- The LocalCustomProperties bag stores everything as a string, so if you want to do numerical work with them, you have to convert them first.
- If you've set up a term hierarchy within the termset (for instance, you have 25 items under Nissan and 40 under Honda), you'd need to set up a function to run that last statement recursively to build the list.

Comment: Thanks, i will try and give feedback and mark as answer. I have only one termset with hierarchical terms. Therefore your solution should work.

Comment: If you have all the terms sitting at the first level you should be fine. If you have multiple levels you want to iterate through the termlist.Terms collection (and if you have more than 2 levels, you'd need to do so recursively, of course).

Comment: The terms are sitting in a hierarchie with 3 levels. I have googled and termset.getallterms would return a flat list of terms. Perhaps i dint need to iterate.

Comment: It is not possible to do a .FindAll on a TermSet. It seems that both a TermCollection and a TermSet are not LINQ'able ! Or am i wrong? (i need to use Server Side Object Model)

Comment: You might need to stuff the terms into another kind of collection first, like a list. The issue there may be that termsets are made to be multi-dimensional in nature, whereas you don't so much care about that...